# Python MIT lectures : log(n) complexity of the example

Tags: python, big-o

There is a code from MIT python programing course , lecture 8 .

```
def(x):
    assert type(x) == int and x >= 0
    answer = 0 
    s = str(x)
    for c in s :
        answer += int(c)
    return answer
```

As professor says , complexity of this code is log  base 10 of  (x). 
He explains it (as i was able to understand)  that, each loop iteration,  C  can be one of the ten digits (0-9)  and this brings  base 10  to logarythm.

However i cannot understand , why it is so? Cause complexity actually depends of the length of list S , rather than    variations  of choice for C.

Can somebody explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you actually answered your question already:

> complexity actually depends of the length of list S , rather than variations of choice for C

The length of list `S` is the number of digits in the number `x`. And the number of digits in a number is the floor of its log, plus one.

```
Range of numbers   Range of log (base 10) value    Number of digits
           1 - 9                         [0, 1)                   1
         10 - 99                         [1, 2)                   2
       100 - 999                         [2, 3)                   3
     1000 - 9999                         [3, 4)                   4
   10000 - 99999                         [4, 5)                   5
```

So, whatever the number is, the only thing matters here is the number of digits in it, and that number is equal to `floor(log10(x)) + 1`.

This can be generalized to any number base: The number `n` of digits in the `b`-base representation of an integer `x` is equal to floor value of `b`-base log of `x` plus `1`.

For example, the number of bits in binary numbers would be

```
Decimal range    Binary range    Range of log (base 2) value    Number of bits
            1               1                         [0, 1)                 1
        2 - 3         10 - 11                         [1, 2)                 2
        4 - 7       100 - 111                         [2, 3)                 3
       8 - 15     1000 - 1111                         [3, 4)                 4
      16 - 31   10000 - 11111                         [4, 5)                 5
```

Answer (score 6):

The time spent depends on the number of digits in `x` as a decimal number. The number of digits in a positive decimal number `x` is `floor(log10(x)) + 1` ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases) has a good explanation as to why this is true):

```
>>> from math import log10
>>> 
>>> x = 12345
>>> int(log10(x)) + 1
5
```

Hence the time complexity goes as log10, as the professor states. In other words, as `x` increases, the number of digits we need to process increases as `log10(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

> He explains it (as i was able to understand) that, each loop iteration, C can be one of the ten digits (0-9) and this brings base 10 to logarythm.

That’s not the reason. It doesn’t matter *which* values `c` can take. What matters is *how many* values it takes – and the answer is: it takes one value for each digit in `x`. And `x` has O(log<sub>10</sub>*x*) decimal digits. That’s just how number representations work: a representation of any number *n* in any base *b* has log<sub>*b*</sub>*n*+1 digits.

Comment: Thank you , i`ll remeber this as an axiom.